# Force append to buffer instead of at point

Tags: buffers, ipython, yank, keystrokes

Is it possible to force an Emacs buffer to place any new text it receives at the end of the buffer, instead of at the mouse point? I mean all of: keystrokes, yanks, mouse paste. I'm thinking in particular of buffers such as `*IPython*`, where the moment you press enter, the line is actually echoed and executed at the end of the buffer. But in general, the issue applies to all terminal-like buffers, where it doesn't make sense to paste text anywhere but at the end.

Comment: For an example, see [`comint-preinput-scroll-to-bottom`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/comint.el?id=866501efe0fdc0c29448e0aaf8696eb0a3c8fcd6#n2090) which is added to `pre-input-hook` in `comint-mode`

Comment: correction to my above comment: it is added to `pre-command-hook`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hook into `before-change-functions`:

```el
(add-to-list 'before-change-functions #'(lambda (_b _e) (goto-char (point-max))))
```

Comment: `C-h f end-of-buffer`: "*This function is for interactive use only;
in Lisp code use `(goto-char (point-max))' instead.*"